# How to show cartesian product of 2 fields is isomorphic to another field

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, field-theory

In the highlighted question below, how would I prove that $G$ is isomorphic to another field in order to prove that $G$ is a field?  Also, is it sufficient to solve the system of equations

\begin{array}{l}ax-by=1\\ay+bx-by=0,\end{array}.

in order to show the existence of mulitiplicative inverses?  Would solving the system of equations and finding a general formula for multiplicative inverses guarantee that their aren't any elements in $G$ that may not have a multiplicative inverse?

> Let F be a field such that $$p(x):=x^2+x+1\neq 0$$
>
> for all $x\in F$.  Let $G=F \times F$ with elements written $(a,b)=a+jb$, $a,b\in F $, for a formal symbol $j$.  Define addition componentwise
>
> $$(a+jb)+(c+jd)=(a+c)+j(b+d)$$,
>
> and define multiplication by the rule that $j^2+j+1=0$:
>   $$(a+jb)(c+jd)=(ac-bd)+j(ad+bc-bd)$$.
>
> Show that $G$ with these additions and mulitplications is a field.

Comment: $G$ is not the Cartesian product of two fields. The Cartesian product of two fields would have a multiplication operation defined by $(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac, bd)$. It's merely the underlying set of $G$ that is the Cartesian product of the underlying set of $F$ with itself. (or, alternatively the product could be seen at the level of the underlying additive abelian groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $p$ is irreducible over $F$, and $G$ is the field $F(j)$ obtained by adjoining to it a root $j$ of $p$.  Note that the formula for $(a+jb)(c+jd)$ arises by expanding out the product and substituting $-j - 1$ for $j^2$.  Also, the other root of $p$ is $\overline{j} = -1-j$, so 
$$\dfrac{a+jb}{c+jd}  = \dfrac{(a+jb)(c+\overline{j}c)}{(c+jd)(c+\overline{j}d)} = \dfrac{ac-ad+bd + j(bc-ad)}{c^2-cd+d^2} $$

Comment: Ok.  this then shows that the denominator $\neq 0$, which suggests that mulitplicative inverses exist?

Comment: It doesn't "suggest" it, it shows what the multiplicative inverse is!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me!